# How to rearrange a Discussion Board on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-discussion-board

I currently have a flat view of a discussion board, and I’ve been tasked with rearranging it slightly. Wondering if there is a way to:

1. Make the replies on a discussion board post default to newest replies (getting rid of oldest replies option would be nice).
2. Move to reply box from the very bottom to the top of the reply section.

I cannot code and am seeking a way to do it without coding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, there is no OOTB way to customize discussion board. If you want to customize it, you must should use codes.